# StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter Vs StrutsPrepareFilter and StrutsExecuteFilter

Tags: java, struts2

I am learning Struts2. I have a question in mind what is the difference between in these two implementation of Filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**And**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is both have same behavior or not. My opinion is that they both are different but I don't in which term.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know which term, then you don't have an opinion.

Comment: nice one :-P Infact I posted a question yesterday and you also commented on it. Someone told me to use first approach rather than 2nd one and doing this my issue resolve. I successfully able to render response in jsp view. Roman be a answerers rather than a commentor ;)

Comment: The first approach is for some other filters that need an action context before the action is executed. In the previous post you didn't post `web.xml`, so I have nothing to answer. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They identical, StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter is a combination of StrutsPrepareFilter and StrutsExecuteFilter, have a look at the implementation here

- [StrutsPrepareFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.1.6/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareFilter.java)
- [StrutsExecuteFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.2.1/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsExecuteFilter.java)
- [StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.2.1/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java)

Notice is only:

```
Handles both the preparation and execution phases of the Struts dispatching 
process.
This filter is better to use when you don't have another filter that needs 
access to action context information, such as Sitemesh.
```